# Как вводить символы с клавиатуры до первой точки?

Tags: c

Требуется вводить символы до тех пор, пока не встретится точка. Эта программа не реагирует на точку. В чем ошибка? (Или предложите, пожалуйста, свой рабочий вариант)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
    char ar[1000];
    char ch; int i = 0;
    scanf_s("%s", &ch); ar[i] = ch;
    while ( ch!= '.') {
        scanf_s("%s", &ch);
        ar[i] = ch;
        i++; 
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вы как-то криво используете `scanf_s`, да и не нужна она тут. Просто `scanf("%c", &ch);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Для ввода одного символа функцию `scanf` (или её "безопасный" вариант `scanf_s`) нужно использовать следующим образом:

```
scanf_s("%c", &ch, 1);
```

2) Для считывания одного символа из стандартного ввода можно также использовать функцию `getchar`:

```
ch = getchar();
```

3) Оба предыдущих варианта сработают только после нажатия клавиши `Enter`. Если нужна мгновенная реакция после ввода символа точки, нужно использовать функцию `getch`:

```
ch = getch();
```

Но при использовании этого способа на консоли не будут выведены вводимые символы. Чтобы они появлялись, их нужно будет выводить самим:

```
ch = getch();
putchar(ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int main(void)
{
    printf("Hello World!\n");

    char c = '\0';
    while (c != '.') {
        scanf("%c", &c);
        printf("%c\n", c);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Думаю, проблема в вызове `scanf_c`. Во-первых, если Вам нужно посимвольное считывание, следует использовать формат `%c`, во-вторых scanf_s нужен третий аргумент. В-третьих, у Вас в `ar[0]` попадет только второй введенный символ.

Comment: А зачем `scanf_s` третий аргумент? У неё и второго может не быть.

Comment: @kff Взял отсюда: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf. У меня не винды, scanf_c у меня вообще компилятор не понимает)

Comment: Компилер старый. Или поддержка `c11` не включена. А по ссылке у `scanf_s` один обязательный параметр (формат), а остальные (заполняемые переменные) - необязательные. Вы её, видимо, перепутали с чем-то типа `fscanf/fscanf_s/sscanf/sscanf_s`, у них, действительно, обычно не менее трёх аргументов.

Comment: @kff, я, откровенно, не могу разобраться с функцией `scanf_s`. Компиляторы сс, gcc c поддержкой стандарта С11 ее не видит (Ubuntu 14.04). В стандарте (по ссылкам на этом сайте) я ее найти не могу. То, что ей таки нужен третий аргумент при символах формата `%s%c%]` написано во всех ссылках, которые я видел, в т.ч. в вышеприведенной.

Comment: Извиняюсь. Был невнимателен. Всё верно, нужен ещё один аргумент: `scanf_s and wscanf_s require the buffer size to be specified for all input parameters of type c, C, s, S, or string control sets that are enclosed in []. The buffer size in characters is passed as an additional parameter immediately following the pointer to the buffer or variable.` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx)